# How do I check if a value is in a nested python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

How do I check if a value is in a nested python dictionary?

I want to check if the choice the user enters is in the dictionary and if not add the new movie to the dictionary, and if it is to state the movie is already stored.

I would also like the user to enter movie choice and the dictionary to print the details of the that particular movie rather than all 10.

Click on link to view picture of code.

**This is the written code:**

```
topMovies = {1:{'Movie':'Avatar', 'Year': '2009', 'Gross Profit': '£2.788 billion', 'Budget': '£237 million'},
2:{'Movie':'Titanic', 'Year': '1997', 'Gross Profit': '£2.187 billion', 'Budget': '£200 million'},
3:{'Movie':'Star Wars: The Force Awakens', 'Year': '2015', 'Gross Profit': '£2.068 billion', 'Budget': '£306 million'},
4:{'Movie':'Avengers: Infinity War', 'Year': '2018', 'Gross Profit': '£1.814 billion', 'Budget': '£400 million'},
5:{'Movie':'Jurassic World', 'Year': '2015', 'Gross Profit': '£1.672 billion', 'Budget': '£150 million'},
6:{'Movie':'The Avengers', 'Year': '2012', 'Gross Profit': '£1.519 billion', 'Budget': '£220 million'},
7:{'Movie':'Fast and Furious 7', 'Year': '2015', 'Gross Profit': '£1.516 billion', 'Budget': '£190 million'},
8:{'Movie':'Avengers: Age of Ultron', 'Year': '2015', 'Gross Profit': '£1.405 billion', 'Budget': '£444 million'},
9:{'Movie':'Black Panther', 'Year': '2018', 'Gross Profit': '£1.344 billion', 'Budget': '£210 million'},
10:{'Movie':'Harry Potter and the Deathly Hollows: Part 2', 'Year': '2011', 'Gross Profit': '£1.342 billion', 'Budget': '£250 million (shared with part 1)'}}

for movieID, movieInfo in topMovies.items():
    print("\nNumber: ", movieID)
    for key in movieInfo:
        print(key , ": " , movieInfo[key])
print("\n")

#checking if movie already stored and if not add new movie else movie is already stored
choice = input('Please enter choice: ')
for x in topMovies:
    if choice != topMovies[x]:
        print("Enter new movie!")
        topMovies[x] = {}
        topMovies[x]['Movie'] = choice
        topMovies[x]['Year'] = input('Enter the year of release for the movie: ')
        topMovies[x]['Gross Profit'] = input('Enter the gross profit of the movie: ')
        topMovies[x]['budget'] = input('Enter the budget for the movie: ')
        print("\n")
        print(topMovies[x])
    elif choice == topMovies[x]['Movie']:
        print("Movie already stored!")
    break
```

Comment: What is your specific problem? What isn't working in your code?

Comment: This is a task for a school project. I can't get it to search for values in the dictionary.  I need the user to enter their movie choice and the program to check if their movie is in the dictionary as a value and if so to let them know it is already stored. If it is not in the dictionary it will be added to the dictionary and the other aspects (budget, year and profit). Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to test the value of `choice` against all movies `'Movie'` values *before* letting the user create a new entry:

```
choice = input('Please enter choice: ')
for movie in topMovies.values():
    if movie["Movie"] == choice:
        print("Movie already stored!")
        break
else:
   # IMPORTANT: this is a 'else' for the `for` loop, 
   # it will only be executed if the loop terminates 
   # without a `break`

   # create the movie here - warning: you'll need to find 
   # the highest `topMovies` key to compute the new movie key.
```

Note that this solution is inefficient (sequential scanning is O(N)) and not as readable as it could be. You could improve it by using a better datastructure - when you see a dict whose keys are consecutive ascending integers chances are you want a `list` instead - and a reverse index (a dict mapping movies names to their index in the list).

```
top_movies = [
    {'Movie':'Avatar', 'Year': '2009', 'Gross Profit': '£2.788 billion', 'Budget': '£237 million'},
    {'Movie':'Titanic', 'Year': '1997', 'Gross Profit': '£2.187 billion', 'Budget': '£200 million'},
    {'Movie':'Star Wars: The Force Awakens', 'Year': '2015', 'Gross Profit': '£2.068 billion', 'Budget': '£306 million'},
    {'Movie':'Avengers: Infinity War', 'Year': '2018', 'Gross Profit': '£1.814 billion', 'Budget': '£400 million'},
    {'Movie':'Jurassic World', 'Year': '2015', 'Gross Profit': '£1.672 billion', 'Budget': '£150 million'},
    {'Movie':'The Avengers', 'Year': '2012', 'Gross Profit': '£1.519 billion', 'Budget': '£220 million'},
    {'Movie':'Fast and Furious 7', 'Year': '2015', 'Gross Profit': '£1.516 billion', 'Budget': '£190 million'},
    {'Movie':'Avengers: Age of Ultron', 'Year': '2015', 'Gross Profit': '£1.405 billion', 'Budget': '£444 million'},
    {'Movie':'Black Panther', 'Year': '2018', 'Gross Profit': '£1.344 billion', 'Budget': '£210 million'},
    {'Movie':'Harry Potter and the Deathly Hollows: Part 2', 'Year': '2011', 'Gross Profit': '£1.342 billion', 'Budget': '£250 million (shared with part 1)'}
    ]

movies_index = {movie["Movie"].lower(): index for index, movie in enumerate(top_movies)}

# ....

choice = input('Please enter choice: ').strip()
# dict lookup is O(1) and highly optimised
if choice.lower() in movies_index:
    print("Movie already stored!")
else:
    new_movie = {"Movie": choice}
    # fill in the fields
    # ...
    top_movies.append(new_movie)
    movies_index[choice.lower()] = len(top_movies) - 1
```

Answer (score -2):

EDIT 2: This doesn't work in your example. Letting it stay as an example of "not reading the entire problem"

If you're looking for efficiency, would this work:

```
choice = input("Movie name please: ...")
if {"Movie":choice} not in topMovies.values():
    etc etc etc
```

EDIT: full example since the above didn't work out of the box without fitting to your code...

```
topMovies={}
topMovies["1"]={"Movie":"Avatar"}
choice = input("Movie name please: ...")
if {"Movie":choice} not in topMovies.values():
    X=input("Rank: ")
    topMovies[X]={}
    topMovies[X][choice]=choice
```

Comment: I did.
a = {"1":{"a":"3"},"2":{"a":"4"}}
{"a":"3"} in a.values()

output: True

Comment: You failed - the values in `topMovies` have more key:values pair than just `{"Movie": <name>}` so your test will always be false.  `d = {1: {"foo": "bar", "baaz": "quux"}}; {"foo": "bar"} in d.values()` => False.

Comment: True. My bad Didn't think about that aspect. :( I deserve the downvotes!